# CSS Slide images without scale

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've made "image slider" where when I hover over one image it zooms in and shows info (it should show some info) right now it's not, I was gonna ask how can I make them **not** jam like this (img below) and show only 1 portion of it, do you have any ideas?

[image]

```
<div class=" " id="approach-img">
    <ul class="row ">
        <li class="col-md-3">
            <img src="https://cdn.homedit.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/modern-interior-design-apatment-brazil.jpg" />
        </li>
        <li class="col-md-3">
            <img src="https://cdn.homedit.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/modern-interior-design-apatment-brazil.jpg" />
        </li>
        <li class="col-md-3">
            <img src="https://cdn.homedit.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/modern-interior-design-apatment-brazil.jpg" />
        </li>
        <li class="col-md-3">
            <img src="https://cdn.homedit.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/modern-interior-design-apatment-brazil.jpg" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#approach-img ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}  


#approach-img ul li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*width: 250px;*/
  overflow: hidden;

  -webkit-transition: width .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: width .5s ease;
  -o-transition: width .5s ease;
  transition: width .5s ease;
}

#approach-img ul li img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width:600px;
  height:400px;
}

#approach-img ul:hover li {
   width: calc((100% - 600px)/3);
}
#approach-img ul:hover li:hover {
  width: 600px;
}
```

I dont have time to put it on codepen sry!!

Comment: Can you please include the relevant code with your question. It will be much easier for us to help you.. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask -- https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I know I know sry... code is comming ...

Comment: Have you tried using background-images? Another possibility would be to wrap the images in a parent and have the parent cut them off using overflow:hidden. Also please share your code!

Comment: Hmm i did use bacground-images and it works pretty nice...but is there any other way ...do you have any example or name of this idk what's this even called

Comment: I tried your code in Chrome and Firefox and I don't see the jam effect you described in your question. And I don't think this kind of slider has a name really... at least none I could think of.

Comment: I found [this](https://codepen.io/ferry/pen/ZYVwxz) searching for "image accordion"

Comment: I've seen it referred to as an "accordion slider" sometimes, but not sure how common the name is or if there's a more common one.

Comment: @Maharkus hmmm funny ..I tried it too, maybe its cuz its only part of my code for website ..maybe some other class or something jams it ...
thanks this is it ..I needed something like this thanks